IV Rank/Relevance Condition Linear Algebra Intuition
Consider the following econometric model (IV) :  $Y_1 = X'\beta + e$, where $Y_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ is some outcome variable of interest, and we have a set of regressors $X = \begin{bmatrix} Z_1 \\ Y_2 \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^k$. ($Z_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{k_1}, Y_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{k_2}, k_1 + k_2 = k \:$) Suppose that we potentially have some confounders, so that $\mathbb{E}[Xe] \neq 0$. But suppose we also have some instrumental variables $Z=\begin{bmatrix}Z_1\\Z_2 \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathcal{l}}$, such that $\mathbb{E}[Ze] =0, \mathbb{E}[ZZ']$ is psd, and $\mathbb{E}[ZX']$ has rank $k$ (Relevance).
I'm curious about the relevance condition: $\mathbb{E}[ZX']$ must have rank $k$. I can understand the connection here to $Cov(X, Z)$, but I'm just shy of a nice, geometric intuition for why the rank condition implies this (Something to do with what the $Z$ transformation does to the columns of $X$), and how this must in a sense 'preserve' at least the dimension of $X$ to be relevant.
Also, to me this seems somewhat related to our rank condition in the original OLS case: $\hat{\beta} = (X'X)^{-1}X'Y_1$, where the rank must also be $k$ (This time we want our regressors to be linearly independent and each 'offer something new'). Again this generalizes the simplest form of $\beta$ as $\frac{Cov}{Var}$.
To summarize, I'm missing some geometric intuition for what these transformations tell us about the variance/covariance of different variables in space. I.e. what intuitive, geometric connection does the form $ZX'$ have to explaining the covariation between those variables? With $X'X$ for example, I can see how $Var(X) = Cov(X, X) = \mathbb{E}[XX']$ when $X$ is demeaned (Or includes a constant), and thus becomes $\frac{1}{n} \mathbf{X'X}$ with a sample. With $\mathbb{E}[ZX']$ above, why do we need rank = $k$ for the $Cov$ to 'not be 0'?

I am unable to make sense of your first paragraph because you haven't described any random variables at all!  Please clarify what kind of mathematical objects $Z$ and $X$ are intended to be.

I do not know if that meets your requirement for intuition, but if the rank was less than $k$, we would have fewer instruments than regressors, so not enough exogenous variation to identify the parameters.

Your notation remains misleading--it states explicitly that $Z$ and $X$ are real vectors--but the context indicates you are treating them both as vector-valued random variables.  Moreover, some of your assumptions look irrelevant or distracting.  E.g., the possibility of confounders is not related to your question about understanding the rank of $E[Z^\prime X].$

I posted an answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/658579/919, which concerns the same idea but in a more general setting: namely, geometric intuition concerning the relationship between the rank of a variance-covariance matrix and the rank of a random variable.

Very helpful, thank you

If I understand correctly, the primary question concerns the rationale behind the rank condition in instrumental variable (IV) estimation.
Consider the structural model in matrix form:
$$
Y = X\beta + \epsilon,
$$
where $ Y \in \mathbb{R}^n $ represents the outcome, $ X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d} $ is the matrix of endogenous regressors, and $ Z \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k} $ is the matrix of $ k \geq d $ instrumental variables.
First Stage
The first stage involves predicting the endogenous variables $ X $ using the instruments $ Z $ through projection:
$$
\hat{X} = Z \left(Z^\top Z\right)^{-1} Z^\top X.
$$
Second Stage
The predicted values $ \hat{X} $ are then used in the second stage to estimate $ \beta $:
$$
\hat{\beta}_{IV} = \left(\hat{X}^\top \hat{X}\right)^{-1} \hat{X}^\top Y.
$$
To compute $ \hat{\beta}_{IV} $, the matrix $ \hat{X}^\top \hat{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d} $ must be invertible, which is equivalent to requiring that $ \operatorname{rank}(\hat{X}^\top \hat{X}) = \operatorname{rank}(\hat{X}) = d $
Linking to the Rank Condition
Under the assumption that $Z^\top Z$ is invertible, the ranks of $ (Z^\top Z)^{-1} $ and of $ Z(Z^\top Z)^{-1} $ are both equal to $ k $. The rank of $ \hat{X} $, determined by the product $ Z(Z^\top Z)^{-1} Z^\top X $, satisfies:
$$
\operatorname{rank}(\hat{X}) \leq \min\{\operatorname{rank}(Z(Z^\top Z)^{-1}), \operatorname{rank}(Z^\top X)\}.
$$
Thus, the rank of $ \hat{X} $ is limited by the rank of $ Z^\top X $. To ensure $ \hat{X} $ has rank $ d $, it must be true that:
$$
d \leq \min\{k, \operatorname{rank}(Z^\top X)\}.
$$
If $Z^\top X$ is not full rank, i.e., $ \operatorname{rank}(Z^\top X) = r < d\leq k $, then $\min\{k, r\}=r$, but this contradicts the requirement of $d\leq r$ to make $ \hat{X}^\top \hat{X} $ invertible.
The rank condition ensures that the second-stage regression is feasible. Specifically, $ Z^\top X $ must be full rank ($ \operatorname{rank}(Z^\top X) = d $) to guarantee that $ \hat{X}^\top \hat{X} $ is invertible, thereby enabling the IV estimator $ \hat{\beta}_{IV} $ to be computed.
In population covariance
Every entry of the matrix $\mathbb{E}\left[Z^\top X\right]$ corresponds to:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[Z^\top X\right]_{i,j} = \mathbb{E}[Z_iX_j]=\operatorname{Cov}(Z_i,X_j) + \mathbb{E}[Z_i]\mathbb{E}[X_j].
$$
Without loss of generality, consider that $X$ and $Z$ have been demeaned, so $\mathbb{E}[Z_i]=0,\ \forall i\in[k]$ and $\mathbb{E}[X_j]=0,\ \forall j\in[d]$. Thus:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[Z^\top X\right]_{i,j} =\operatorname{Cov}(Z_i,X_j).
$$
Now consider the case of an exposure, $X_l$ with $l\in[d]$ that is uncorrelated with all instruments; i.e., $Z$ is not relevant for $X_l$. Therefore:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[Z^\top X\right]_{i,l} =\operatorname{Cov}(Z_i,X_l)=0.
$$
This implies that column $l$ of matrix $\mathbb{E}\left[Z^\top X\right]$ is full of zeros, so its rank cannot be $d$; it would be $d-1$ at most. Thus, the IV estimand cannot be computed at the population level.

Thank you for the clear response Johan, it is helpful. I understand the rationale of the condition in the formal justification. I'm more looking for an understanding of what the rank condition tells us about the covariance. I've edited the last paragraph of my question above to clarify.

@rudinable Added a new piece about the covariance that maybe solves the question.

Exactly what I was looking for, thanks
